# What happens to root view controller in ios / swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Say I am switching viewcontrollers manually like this
[How to transition to a new view controller with code only using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167073/how-to-transition-to-a-new-view-controller-with-code-only-using-swift)

What happens to the (root) controller when another viewcontroller is brought to front. Can I just reinstantiate it or should I keep a reference to it pu i to front?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to re-instantiate it. You can access all the current `UIViewControllers` from the `UINavigationController` like this

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers
```

This will return an `[UIViewController]`. If you want to get the viewController it is at `index = 0`. If you want to get back to the `root` you can call

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: how do you de-allocate a view contoller? Via `dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)`? Will that essentially "destroy" the view controller until it is re-instantiated?

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` is used when you `presentViewControllerAnimated()` and `popViewControllerAnimated` is used to go back one viewController in the stack of viewcontrollers of the `UINavigationController`. Yes both cases (dismiss/pop) de-allocates and destroys the viewController

Comment: You are supposing that his UIViewController is embedded in a navigation controller, that is not always true.

Comment: I am / want to / prefer to switch UIViewControllers myself without depending on anything else (I am porting code from another language where transition stack/logic already has been coded - hence I am trying to get close as 1:1 the code there for now )

Answer (score 1):

I would've added this as a comment, just that I don't have enough points.
To answer your question - you should not have to worry about re-instantiating the previous View Controller. If you are using the   `presentViewController:animated:completion` method, you can use the `presentedViewController` and `presentingViewController` properties from the UIViewController class that are set after the transition.

The developers link below will help you decide better on how to handle View Controllers transition depending on your use case -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentedViewController