# segue shrinks viewcontroller. how to keep "normal" size

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Setup embedded viewcontroller tabs using UISegmentedControl and embedded ViewControllers (as in this example: https://ahmedabdurrahman.com/2015/08/31/how-to-switch-view-controllers-using-segmented-control-swift/)

Its all good. The tabs work. The UI changes. BUT, when I touch a button in one of the embedded VC's then I want to launch yet another ViewController ("Z". Simple enough? NO!  In Interface Builder, when I add the segue to the "Z" controller then IB automatically resizes it in the storyboard. It shrinks to the size of the View associated with the UISegmentedControl.

Is there some **setting in IB to tell it to make this "Z" control back to normal size**? Its messed up when I run it in the simulator too: stuff gets cut off, unless I put a spring to the bottom of the screen.

And/or is there something I can do on the segue or something so it doesn't shrink the target ViewController when I drag the seque to it?

Original size of "Z" ViewController:
Top VC is from the View for the UISegmentedControl.
Second VC is the embedded VC.
Third is the "Z", the one embedded should launch.
[image: Before dragging segue onto "Z"]

Drag Segue and it becomes as small as the view on the original ViewController (A). (A embeds B, the B segues to Z).
[image: After dragging seque onto it then the size becomes truncated. And is truncated when run too.]
Note:
Simulated Size: Fixed
I can change the Simulated Size: to Freeform and play with the height; but, not sure what that does, or if that's going to be inflexible for various screen sizes.

Comment: Oh yeah, to make it even more mysterious. One button in B launches Z; but, Z is truncated/small. Yet, if I have a segue to Z already existing on a button in A but outside of the UISegmentedControl then its "all good". Z will launch in normal, full screen, and does not get truncated/shortened in IB. !!!

Comment: Ended up launching these by code instead. That works as expected. Just need to use self.show(nextVC, sender: self) and not use self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Change the simulated size from fixed to freeform then change the values to whatever you'd like.